# Grimmett and Stirzaker Ex 3.11.20 p85

Tags: probability

Let R(p) be the reliability function of a network G, each edge is working with probability p.

(a) Show that $R(p_1p_2) \leq R(p_1)R(p_2) $ if $0 \leq p_1, p_2 \leq 1$

Their proof is:

$P$(edge is blue) $= p_1$ 
$P$(edge is yellow) $= p_2$
$P$(edge is green) $= p_1p_2$

$p_1$ and $p_2$ are independent of each other and all other edges.
An edge is green if is is both yellow and blue,

If there is a working green connection, then there is also a blue and green connection.

Thus:

\begin{align}
P(\text{green connection}) &\leq P(\text{blue connection and yellow connection})\\ 
&=P(\text{blue connection})P(\text{yellow connection})  
\end{align}

Thing is this is not really a proof just a statement of the result?

Where does the $\leq$ come from in the first line? Given that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are independent I would expect their to be an equality as shown in the second line? What have I missed?

Comment: What exactly is meant by a connection?  If it is a monochrome path between two nodes, then I guess what is meant is that if there is a green connection then there is certainly a blue connection and a yellow connection, (the same path) but there might be another path with all yellow edges and yet another path with all blue edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is rather terse. In greater detail, imagine coloring each edge in the network blue with probability $p_1$, and also color each edge yellow with probability $p_2$, with all colorings independent. Identify an edge being blue with the edge working under the "blue" regime, and identify an edge being yellow with the edge working under the "yellow" regime. If the edge is both blue and yellow, it's considered working under the "green" regime; under the "green" regime, any given edge has probability $p_1p_2$ of working.

Recall the reliability function under any given regime is defined as the *expectation* of the *indicator* that a path of the given color exists between source and sink. The point here is that if a green path exists, then a blue path exists and a yellow path exists, but not conversely, because the blue and yellow paths may not cover the same edges. In symbols,
$$
I(\text{green path exists})\le I(\text{blue path exists})I(\text{yellow path exists}).
$$
Taking expectations and using independence yields the result.